# How to access the parameter of one methods to the other method

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a project to do and i have several classes.

In one of the classes i have those two methods:

```
  public byte [] getFirstFinalSum(byte [] firstSum) {

  System.out.println("the first final sum is" +Arrays.toString(firstSum));
  return firstSum;

  }
```

My second Method:

```
    public byte [] getSecondFinalSum(byte [] secondSum) {

 galoaField256 d = new galoaField256 (); // create new reference 
    d.setGeneratorPolynom(3);
    d.getGeneratorPolynom();
    d.setString("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
    d.getString();
    d.loadExp();
    d.loadLog();

  byte [] finVector=new byte [4];

 System.out.println("the second final sum is" +Arrays.toString(secondSum));

 for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {

     finVector[i]=(byte)d.add(firstSum[i],secondSum[i]);


 }

  return finVector;

 }
```

Now what i have to do is to use to my second method firstSum[i] which is the parameter of the first method. I know i can not have access to that local variable because of the scope of variables. The problem is that the first method is called by another class which is different from that class and also different from the class which second method is called. Another problem is that those methods are called within a methods which their return types do not give us the result we want to pass to those methods parameters as arguments.

I am an OCAJP and OCPJP oracle certificate holder and i know about inner classes but i am not sure if i use the second method : getSecondFinalSum as a method inside the first method by applying inner classes principle. I did that but i also am not able to access firstSum[i] inside the second method. Can anyone show me how can i achieve that?

Comment: What is up with the indentation? It's unreadable. Please paste the whole code and make it clearer to read.

Comment: This is too unclear to be answered.  [edit] your post to include the complete structure and show where the methods `getFirstFinalSum` and `getSecondFinalSum` are called.  You should be figuring out how to pass the necessary data in, not how to extract it from the parameter of another method (which is impossible in Java anyway).

Answer (score -2):

If similar situation arises to me I would have declared a GLOBAL var and unset it after use. I know its not a so secure way. but it works.

Comment: A global ***VAR*** ? Is this [tag:javascript] ?

Comment: declare a GLOBAL variable temp. and perform.
temp=arg1;

Comment: java does not have a gloabal variable

Comment: @BarletSouth public static fields on public classes are essentially global variables.

Comment: ok but you can not call them global variable in java .you can call them class instance . Anyway could you tell me if you know any way how to instaniate a method local inner class in another class